# Cakephp : inserting Image in view with class and alt tag

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tried to render something like this using html helper:

```
<a href="#" class="some-class"><img src="url/to/image.png" alt="alt-tag" /></a>
```

I write this in my .ctp file:

```
 <?php
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("image.png", array("alt" => "alt-tag")),"#", array('class' => 'some-class'));
?>
```

But in browser, image was not displaying but simple plain text :

```
<img src="/url/to/image.png" alt="alt-tag" />
```

I did `inspect element`, where everything look as what I wanted to render. I tried to edit it live, so I selected `edit as html` option in inspect element. I surprised to see following code:

```
<a href="#" class="some-class">&lt;img src="/url/to/image.png" alt="alt-tag" /&gt;</a>
```

Please not that insted of < and > it was `&lt;` and  `&gt;`.

I couldn't figure out what is the problem. (I am new to cakephp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `escape` attribute to False

ex:

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("image.png", array("alt" => "alt-tag")),"#", array('class' => 'some-class', 'escape' => false));
```